# How Server can recognize type that got from Client? .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, serialization, tcpclient

I have Client Layer which send data to Server Layer using Tcp and NetworkStream. And Client can send different object types. Client have Registration and Login window, so it can send a User class when it registrating, or string types when its login verification.

So how Server can recognize which type it got? Is it solution to create class which contain User, login data and other data and create inside some int varible. So when Server deserialize this class it depending a value of int veriable do some work?

Edit:Server always accepting TcpClient.

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), serverPort);
server.Start();
while (true)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Wait");
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
 }
```

Comment: `Is it solution to create class which contain User, login data and other data and create inside some int varible. So when Server deserialize this class it depending a value of int veriable do some work?` - yes, that would work. There are many tools that make this process much less painful, like built-in .net serialization if both sides use .net, or else google's protobuf.

Comment: This is too broad, there is no single correct answer, you can imlplement your protocol as you want, you can use BinaryFormatter to serialize the classes and use a shared DLL for the class definition, you can use Json.Net, use a base class and include class type info so it can deserialize all classess, you can use an int identifier and serialize the class by yourself... Choose the method you prefer and best fits your needs, if then you have any concrete problem, ask again.

Comment: Sounds like you're inventing a wheel that already exists